# Add Percentage-Based Factor to Audit Ban Criteria

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, review-suspension

I'm proposing that the criteria for audit-induced review bans be moved from an absolute value over a given timespan to also take into account a percentage factor of passed/failed.

As I understand it, one receives an audit ban after a certain absolute number of audits are failed within a 60 day period. I think it is also universally agreed on that audit questions, as they are chosen by an automated process, may sometimes be either unilaterally bad, with the wrong response required, or borderline such that multiple responses are understandable. So audits necessarily have a false positive rate. Furthermore, audits have an additional false positive rate based on the fact that even good, careful reviewers may miss something, have a brain slip, or a mis-click at times.

Now consider two reviewers who both are of the same quality in conducting reviews, pay equal attention (i.e. neither "robo-reviews"), and are otherwise similar. But one reviewer only reviews a little each day, and the other reviewer attempts to contribute more to the review process by reviewing more items. Or one reviewer only acts sporadically, and the other makes a daily habit of reviewing.

The more frequent reviewer will receive more audits, hit more false positives, and therefore have a greater chance of being banned. This seems to me a misfeature.

In pseudo-code I imagine that the current logic for a ban looks something like `recentFailedAudits > n`, for some `n`. I would propose that we move the criteria to something like `recentFailedAudits > n && recentFailedAudits / totalRecentAudits > m` for some `m` between `[0,1]`. (Personally, I might conservatively choose that `m` to be one standard deviation below the mean, but I don't feel strongly in that regard).

Comment: As I see it: if you're going to punish people for failing audits, you should also give them credit for passing them.

Comment: I'm very much interested in the source of that downvote. Are there any cons to this feature? I can't think of any, I'm honestly curious.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276118/passing-review-audits-should-offset-audit-failures to middling response. The issue really boils down to, should you get benefit from something you should already be doing, ie. reviewing correctly. My opinion is yes, since positive reinforcement works as well, if not better, than negative reinforcement. Knowing that you are reviewing correctly and receiving some benefit for that can only be a good thing.

Comment: This could potentially delay kicking out robo-reviewers. Consider a case where a robo-reviewer gets lucky in their first 2 audits; their average would be brought up significantly, and it would take more than 2 extra failures before they're banned. I'd rather have an occasional good reviewer told to take a break than a lucky fraction of robots getting more time to make bad choices.

Comment: @Dave I might be wrong, but I'm under the impression that proper audits are easy to spot (by robos and non-robos alike), and so crappy audits which are tripped by honest users are amplified in their significance. Plus banning an honest and motivated reviewer unnecessarily can lead to a lot of frustration, and losing that few dozens reviews a day can be a bigger problem in the long run.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hey. It's meta. Only 0.01% of questions here come without down votes.

Comment: Yes, I agree!!! :) Good wages for good stewards!!!

Comment: As a point of comparison, [flag bans are generously percentage-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405).

Answer (score -19):

The effort SO should put towards correcting each of those reviewers is different.

If the prolific reviewer gets better, it matters more to the quality of SO reviews than if the non-prolific reviewer gets better.

Forcing the prolific reviewer to never make errors and improve more is thus "worth more" to SO; the quality of the prolific reviewer *matters more* than that of the occasional one.

On top of that, someone reviewing prolifically should have lots of practice.  They have lots of opportunity to get better.  They also have lots of opportunity to figure out how to game the system.  So a higher standard might be appropriate.

Comment: Maybe blame the DST that I just observed but I can't make sense of your answer =/. Are you saying it would be a bad idea to have that feature?

Comment: I think what you're saying is that reviewers who review frequently should be held to a higher standard, so it's acceptable that they can only fail a smaller proportion of audits. However, as sclv noted in their OP, there are unavoidably a lot of low-quality audits. As a result, frequent reviewers are often banned from reviewing not because they failed to live up to a high standard, but because they got unlucky with several bad audits in a row.