# Can experienced users be exempted from close vote review tests?

Tags: feature-request

Is anyone else highly annoyed by the close vote testing process? I find it insulting. I might have "failed" (and still would have voted the same way after being advised of failure) one of the test questions that apparently get randomly thrown in front of me, but I've passed a much higher percentage of them. I do read the questions and I do think. If I don't have enough domain knowledge, I hit skip.  The moment I am "congratulated" that I've yet again passed one of these stupid tests, I immediately stop working on the queue. So I'm asking that some effort be put forth to "certify" users as "careful close voters" or some such and exempt them from further "testing".

I have made a good faith effort to find a duplicate of this question, but if there is a similar question with a well-reasoned answer, then give me a pointer and close this.

Comment: Related request: [Add percentage based factor to audit ban criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319811/add-percentage-based-factor-to-audit-ban-criteria)

Comment: Just so you don't think we're yanking your chain, [this makes for *exceptionally* good background reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354555/1079354) on the subject.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of brainiac SO users that never once failed an exam or test in their lives that are annoyed as well.  Ranting about it is as effective as talking back to the traffic cop that pulled you over for speeding: "but I've had a license for 30 years!"

Comment: Well, I continue hearing/reading that you want reviewers. But is seems you have enough of the sort that don't mind the testing. It's certainly possible that it is useless to complain. In which case I should stop complaining _and_ stop reviewing.

Comment: I've seen other posts complaining that the verbiage for failing an audit rubs people the wrong way but I think this is the first time I've read someone say they find the text for passing the audit upsetting. Does it just need to have "Congratulations" removed?

Comment: No. I find that somewhat humorous. My inner dialog says "Really?" 
 The notion that I need to be tested at this point in my life in this area is what rubs me the wrong way. And all the negative votes for this question is a further signal that I should also ignore the Meta venue.  I'll handle it by just "bowing out" of close vote reviews. The system seems to be set up to discourage both close-voters and close vote reviewers. I'll find something else to occupy my mind in retirement.

Comment: You could make a feature-request for being able to dissable the succes message from reviews. That way you will still get reviews but you wont get bothered with the concratulations message.

Answer (score 15):

I hate to make you feel worse, but as insulted as you are that you have to do them despite them being so easy to pass, the reality is that a *lot* of users are regularly failing them.  Even users with lots of rep, lots of reviews, or pretty much any other metric anyone has tried to come up with, are often failing audits.  So no, we can't just get rid of them, even for certain types of users.  They're needed.  It would be nice if they weren't, but they are.

Comment: The metric I suggested was both rep and past close vote review performance. The message I get is that nobody seems to think that this will be valid. I have no mechanism to counter that untested assumption so "Adios, farewell, and good riddance".

Answer (score 7):

Endeavor to pay close attention to questions in the review queue and ensure that you're actually reviewing them the right way.  Ensure that you're not falling into traps with your review tasks *just* because you're high rep or have a lot of reviews under your belt.

**Your reputation or your accuracy for reviews matter *not* for this.**  All the audits can do is check if you're paying attention, and little else.  Be sure you're paying attention, and you'll fail less audits.  (Also, if you don't know, skip the review.)

Comment: Yes, I skip. And if I'm getting annoyed or frustrated, I quit. And the first test message constitutes annoyance.

Comment: Seems like the audits are working then.  I see no reason for this to change or be altered.  You getting frustrated is a ***great*** time to stop for a while, since you don't want to be reviewing these in a huff anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's great that there's a modicum of quality control built into the review process, even if it could use some improvement, and I don't resent participating in it.

I don't think people should be exempted from it. Just because someone has been a careful reviewer so far doesn't mean that they can't become careless at a later point, and it will be difficult to detect that that's happened if they've been completely exempted from the quality control checks. There may be some value in reducing the frequency of audits for users who never(ish) fail them, but I don't think it's a good idea for anyone to not be audited at all.