# Why are failed review audits not offset by positive track record?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

This topic was already discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319811/add-percentage-based-factor-to-audit-ban-criteria), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276118/passing-review-audits-should-offset-audit-failures) and indirectly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225417/does-passing-a-review-audit-decrease-the-chance-of-a-ban). However all those threads are from several years ago, so I hope it's okay to reopen the discussion.

I have a little more than 500 rep on StackOverflow, so I recently got access to review queues.

Since then, I've been presented with several review audits (with random frequency, it seems), and, if I recall correctly, **failed two of them**. After the second one, I got banned from review queues for 2 days.

Now, I would say my overall track record is not bad. In fact I only failed two review audits with many passed ones in between, and raised a total of 68 helpful flags out of 142, with only 2 declined.

So why does someone's positive track record have **no weight whatsoever** in determining review bans?

I think this would be only fair, also considering the lack of a proper way to dispute bad audits.

Comment: Because the audit system is garbage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that your positive track record doesn't count is that you might have *suddenly stopped* paying attention while reviewing. Failing an audit doesn't necessarily mean you're a bad reviewer all the time. It just means that you're not doing a very good job right now. For example, failing a review audit might mean that you're just not paying attention—clicking through the review tasks on "autopilot", e.g., because you're tired or distracted.

You really shouldn't be failing review audits. They're meant to be obvious. If they're not, that's a separate issue. (And one that I have argued elsewhere would and should be fixed by allowing moderators to nominate and/or remove posts as audit candidates.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Cody. I'm not sure I agree with this interpretation. Someone's positive track record (helpful flags, passed reviews) should have some statistical significance that they are *not likely* to suddenly stop paying attention. I'm not saying that passed/failed review offset should be 1-to-1, but at least proportional. E.g. 5 (or 10, or 15) passed reviews offset 1 failed review.

Comment: That you've historically made good decisions doesn't mean you haven't suddenly fallen asleep at the wheel. The audit system is designed around the premise that you should never, under any circumstances, be failing audits. Failing one might be a misclick, but failing two is interpreted as a serious problem.

Comment: @blackgreen I have not died so far. So, I have a clear track record of living. Does that mean I'm immortal?

Comment: @VLAZ well of course not, but I might get injured through the course of my life and not die. If the analogy for failing review audits is with "falling asleep at the wheel" (life-threatening danger) and outright "dying", then the bar is much higher than I expected. If failure is not contemplated, I too can agree that a positive track record bears no value in determining bans. But then it's hardly about "stopping and paying attention" anymore, as the failed audit message suggests.

Comment: @blackgreen You don't get banned on your first infraction. Or even the second, unless they come up really close together. I think I have around 10 failed audits but to my knowledge I haven't been banned once. Some of those came when I was learning the ropes. I took them to heart and moved on. Some, however, came when I really wasn't paying attention. I was distracted or otherwise unable to review properly. In those cases the audit system reminded me that I wasn't fit for reviewing, so I just stopped and came back later when I could do a better job.

Comment: @blackgreen Failing review audits isn't equivalent to death. My comment was meant to lightly poke fun of the inductive reasoning by juxtaposing the same structure with different terms. The point is that a positive track record doesn't make you immune to mistakes. I've done them, so I know that. Mistakes don't need to be literally life threatening to be harmful, either. Mistakes in reviews are *at best* neutral but can also cause more work, which is a negative. So, we really do not want mistakes in reviews. There is a still built in tolerance for some errors - we are human, after all.

Comment: "you might have suddenly stopped paying attention while reviewing" -- I can confirm this is absolutely my case, I only fail audits for this reason. This makes audits worth it to me, failures in these make very convenient indication that I need to either have a break or increase focus when reviewing